# TFX tutorial "penguin_tfdv.ipynb" issue TypeCheckError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tfx

I've got this problem. How could I solve this problem?
This is part of the tutorial of TFX. [link to the tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tfx/penguin_tfdv.ipynb#scrollTo=BQspf0ajg9AO)

I changed nothing in the example code.

```
TypeCheckError: Output type hint violation at WriteStatsOutput[train]: expected <class 'apache_beam.pvalue.PDone'>, got <class 'str'>
Full type hint:
IOTypeHints[inputs=((<class 'tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0.statistics_pb2.DatasetFeatureStatisticsList'>,), {}), outputs=((<class 'apache_beam.pvalue.PDone'>,), {})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Apache beam `2.40.x` installed? If yes, you can try using beam `2.39.0` and it fixed the issue as per [this reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/4993#issuecomment-1175141051).

While running the same code in colab with TFX verison `1.9.0` and Tensorflow version `2.9.0`, I haven't got any `TypeCheckError`. Please find the working gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/sanatmpa1/ac76a547d1e15db7d218eec113422fe2/penguin_tfdv.ipynb).

Let me know if it helps. Thank you!